# Doctrine - getChildren() with conditions?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm trying to write a basic plugin for the Symfony based CMS Diem.
I'm trying to list of the child pages for the current page, which I have managed to do:

```
 $page = $this->getPage();
 $this->subpages = $page->getNode()->getChildren();
```

However, I'm unsure of the syntax to use in order to filter the child records with conditions.
I would actually like to get just the records where the is_active field == 1.

I've looked at the documentation and I think I need to use the setBaseQuery method, but I could really do with an example to get me started.

Can anyone help?

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use DQL and prefetch what you need. I strongly recommend using DQL for everything accept a simple `find`

Or you can simple get it from the repository using the build in "magic" functions.
Something like:

```
Doctrine::em()->getRepository('Models\SubPage')->findByIsActive(1);
```

Check out the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#querying)